# Django : Assigning initial values to fields of a form in a subclass of ModelAdmin

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-admin

I am not sure how to assign values to fields in the form when it is presented to the user through the Admin App.What I am trying to do is present a form to the user in which the field called user is already assigned a value and is disabled (cannot be changed) if possible.

Following are my models

```
class modelStudent(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Enrolled Students"  #Name to display in admin interface
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    school           = models.ForeignKey(modelSchool)
    first_name       = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    student_email    = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False)

class modelStudentAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = modelStudent
        exclude = ['student_email']
```

Now this is the admin class for the admin form

```
class modelStudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
form = modelStudentAdminForm
#Only display students that belong to this user

def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(modelStudentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)

    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    else:
        # Get the school instance
        schoolInstance = modelSchool.objects.get(user=request.user)
        qs = modelStudent.objects.filter(school=schoolInstance)
        return qs

def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    #modelStudentAdmin.form.initial={"first_name":"JoeJoe"}
    return modelStudentAdmin.form

 def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'user':
            kwargs['queryset'] =  modelStudent.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return super(modelStudentAdmin,self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

In this case it says

```
'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

I have tried assigning a value to a form field and was unable to do so.
So my question is how can i mark a field as readonly in the form and assign an initial value ? I would like to do that to the `user` drop down field and also assign an initial value to first_name

**Update:**

I have also implemented the method as stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) (in order to restrict the foreign key options)

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
```

however that is not being called.

Comment: are you already tried like this docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form

Comment: I used `def formfield_for_foreignkey` and its not being called

Comment: how about `def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):`, because in your case the `request` field is filled with `None` `request=None`... perhaps it is the cause..